# Extracting file columns based on header feature

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a large csv matrix file (input.csv) in the following format:

```
Patient,sample 66_pos_LC/MS Pos_con,sample 57_net_LC/MS Neg_dis,sample 1_LC/MS Polar_con,sample 3_LC/MS Neg_net
xx,2.5,-7.8,2.5,3.6
ab 1,5.4,3,0.3
yy,43,33,77,55
```

depending on the first line of the file, I want to split file content based on LC/MS feature. That is, if I want all LC/MS Neg, output file would look like :

output1.csv

```
Patient,sample 57_net_LC/MS Neg_dis,sample 3_LC/MS Neg_net
xx,-7.8,3.6
ab,5.4,0.3
yy,33,55
```

For this I use:

```
head -n 1 input.csv | tr ',' '\n' | cat -n | grep 'LC/MS Neg'
```

This gives the column numbers where I should look (in this case: 3 and 5); to get the above output, I use:

```
cut -d, -f1,3,5 input.csv > output1.csv
```

Although it gives me the desired output, but I find this would be complicated for extracting many columns at a time.

I will highly appreciate some awk/sed solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==1 {
    f[++numFlds] = 1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ sel) {
            f[++numFlds] = i
        }
    }
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=numFlds; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<numFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v sel=Neg -f tst.awk file
Patient,sample 57_net_LC/MS Neg_dis,sample 3_LC/MS Neg_net
xx,-7.8,3.6
ab 1,3,
yy,33,55

$ awk -v sel=Pos -f tst.awk file
Patient,sample 66_pos_LC/MS Pos_con
xx,2.5
ab 1,5.4
yy,43

$ awk -v sel=Polar -f tst.awk file
Patient,sample 1_LC/MS Polar_con
xx,2.5
ab 1,0.3
yy,77

$ awk -v sel='Pos|Neg' -f tst.awk file
Patient,sample 66_pos_LC/MS Pos_con,sample 57_net_LC/MS Neg_dis,sample 3_LC/MS Neg_net
xx,2.5,-7.8,3.6
ab 1,5.4,3,
yy,43,33,55
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat get_cols.awk
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
NR==1 {
    i = 1
    idx[i++] = 1
    for(j=2; j<=NF; j++)
        if($j ~ /LC\/MS Neg/)
            idx[i++] = j
}
{
    for(k=1; k<i; k++)
        printf "%s", k==1 ? $idx[k] : OFS $idx[k]
    print ""
}
```

- set input and output field separator as `,`
- use an array `idx` to save the index we need to print

  - first column is always needed
  - to get the rest, iterate over header fields and see which ones match the criteria
- then print the fields

Run it as:

```
$ awk -f get_cols.awk ip.txt 
Patient,sample 57_net_LC/MS Neg_dis,sample 3_LC/MS Neg_net
xx,-7.8,3.6
ab,5.4,0.3
yy,33,55
```

Same concept with `perl`

```
$ perl -F, -lane '@idx = grep { $F[$_] =~ m|LC/MS Neg| } (1..$#F) if $.==1;
                  print join ",", @F[0,@idx]' ip.txt
Patient,sample 57_net_LC/MS Neg_dis,sample 3_LC/MS Neg_net
xx,-7.8,3.6
ab,5.4,0.3
yy,33,55
```

Comment: awk fields, strings, and arrays all start at 1, not 0. Creating user-defined arrays that start at 0 inevitably leads to confusion and bugs.